# postgreSQL slow query with high shared read

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-10

i have a problem with my postgreSQL database, actually i'm developer not DBA so i don't have enough experience to deal with problems like this.
I ran this query at my psql:

```
explain (analyze true, buffers true) select json_build_object('tracker_id', tracker_id,   
'page_name', page_name, 'post_id',item_id, 'item', item, 'created_time', created_time ,   
'updated_time', updated_time, 'full_picture', full_picture, 'url', url, 'message', message,   
'comments_number', comments_number, 'reactions_count', reactions_count, 'reaction_counts',   
reaction_counts, 'shares_number', shares_number, 'sentiment_label', sentiment_label, 'dialect',   
dialect, 'domain', domain, 'user', from_user, 'attachment', attachment, 'status', status ) FROM   
fb_public_pages_feeds where tracker_id = 10033  AND created_time >= '2021-08-01 21:00:00' AND   
created_time <= '2021-08-10 06:11:25' order by created_time DESC;
```

and here is the result of it:

```
 Sort  (cost=131413.32..131573.66 rows=64136 width=40) (actual time=228599.459..228772.292 rows=114026 loops=1)
   Sort Key: created_time DESC
   Sort Method: external sort  Disk: 90848kB
   Buffers: shared hit=23328 read=182279 dirtied=16582 written=3945, temp read=11356 written=11356
   ->  Index Scan using fb_public_pages_feeds_tracker_id_idx on fb_public_pages_feeds  (cost=0.56..126292.43 rows=64136 width=40) (actual time=35794.622..146061.562 rows=114026 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (tracker_id = 10033)
         Filter: ((created_time >= '2021-08-01 21:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (created_time <= '2021-08-10 06:11:25'::timestamp without time zone))
         Rows Removed by Filter: 32090
         Buffers: shared hit=23328 read=182279 dirtied=16582 written=3945
 Planning time: 1.046 ms
 Execution time: 228814.096 ms
```

as i read, this means that most of data are read from disk which is bad behavior and i need to read it from cache, but despite i ran this query multiple times it never get cached like there is something make my cache always busy.

my system has a heavy work load, hundereds of insertion & updates per minute.
so how can i solve a problem like that? increasing shared buffers or running VACUUM & ANALYZE manually?
**here are my config:**

shared_buffers: 10GB
shared_preload_libraries: ''
work_mem: 10485kB
effective_cache_size: 30GB
autovacuum_analyze_scale_factor     | 0.1
autovacuum_analyze_threshold        | 50
autovacuum_freeze_max_age           | 200000000
autovacuum_max_workers              | 3
autovacuum_multixact_freeze_max_age | 400000000
autovacuum_naptime                  | 1min
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_delay        | 20ms
autovacuum_vacuum_cost_limit        | -1
autovacuum_vacuum_scale_factor      | 0.2
autovacuum_vacuum_threshold         | 50

**and here more information about the table that face this problem from pg_stat_all_tables:**
relname             | fb_public_pages_feeds
seq_scan            | 37418
seq_tup_read        | 31025964155
idx_scan            | 10042277
idx_tup_fetch       | 963803744
n_tup_ins           | 3035565
n_tup_upd           | 9180652
n_tup_del           | 0
n_tup_hot_upd       | 2174258
n_live_tup          | 6253232
n_dead_tup          | 6637730
n_mod_since_analyze | 10332947
last_vacuum         |
last_autovacuum     | 2021-05-28 02:20:45.812805+00
last_analyze        |
last_autoanalyze    | 2021-03-23 18:29:05.939813+00
vacuum_count        | 0
autovacuum_count    | 16
analyze_count       | 0
autoanalyze_count   | 4

my postgreSQL version: PostgreSQL 10.5
system RAM: 64GB
system CPU: 16 CPU

UPDATE:
here is the result of running **VACUUM** manually.
[image]

Comment: You said you ran it multiple times.  Is the plan you show from the first of those, or a later one?

Comment: You should turn on track_io_timing (and probably leave it on,  the overhead is low and the data it produces is very useful)

Comment: What are relpages and reltuples from pg_class?

Comment: @jjanes 
it was the second time for running my query.

Comment: @jjanes
and here are the requested data:
reltuples | 1.28344e+07
relpages  | 6258530

Comment: I don't understand how a table with 50% turn over could go so long without being vacuumed or analyzed. Is something holding a restrictive lock on the table over very long times, or taking a restrictive lock very often? Like, creating and dropping indexes?

Comment: Try a manual vacuum and see if it completes, and if it fixes the problem.

Comment: @jjanes not solved
i kept searching and i found that too many idle connections that runs for a long period of time (hours and days in some cases) to this table.. and actually other tables ... could this be the reason? what makes query goes to idle and how can i solve problem like that?

Comment: @jjanes
do you need any further info to be able to find the solution of this problem?

Comment: @jjanes
i added the result of VACUUM manually.

Comment: Are the connections just "idle", or "idle in transaction"?  They both mean that someone opened a connection, and is now not using it but also not closing it.  But the latter can be much more damaging than the former.  You can use pg_stat_activity to identify a lot about those connections, then go interrogate the people responsible for them.